# PowerShell displaying weird characters after Creators Update

Tags: powershell

I've just installed Creators Update on my machine and upon launching PowerShell, instead of having a clean screen, I see this mess:

[image: PowerShell]

What could be a potential fix?

Comment: See here: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-fix-broken-powershell-in-windows-10-creators-update/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-fix-broken-powershell-in-windows-10-creators-update/),

> "The problem with PowerShell showing gibberish is a font problem.
>   Specifically, the update corrupted rasterized fonts. If PowerShell was
>   set to display text in the corrupted font, you will see a wall of
>   gibberish instead."

The fix is pretty simple.

> "On the Properties window, go to the Font tab. Here, you can change
>   which font PowerShell uses. Select any font that isn’t listed under
>   Rasterized fonts. Close PowerShell for good measure and open it again.
>   The problem should be resolved."

Comment: Worked like a charm!